# Problem on sorting an array

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, sorting

I have problem in sorting an array in ascending form and i don't know how to fix it.

```
string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(fbdialog.SelectedPath.ToString(), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
Array.Sort(filePath);
```

Here are the values of an filePath.

```
"C:\\Documents and Settings\\20110909\\DAR-AAP070127-20110909.ods"
"C:\\Documents and Settings\\20110909\\DAR-ALA061452-09050909.xls"
"C:\\Documents and Settings\\20110819\\DAR-AAP070127-20110819.xls"
```

I want to look like this..

```
"C:\\Documents and Settings\\20110909\\DAR-AAP070127-20110909.ods"
"C:\\Documents and Settings\\20110819\\DAR-AAP070127-20110819.xls"
"C:\\Documents and Settings\\20110909\\DAR-ALA061452-09050909.xls"
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your order?

Comment: @Snowbear I think by filename

Comment: I want to sort it by EmpNo(AAP070127).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort by "EmpNo" e.g. "AAP070127":

```
string[] sortedFiles = Directory
    .GetFiles(fbdialog.SelectedPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .OrderBy(n => Path.GetFileName(n).Split('-')[1])
    .ToArray();
```

**Update**

And without Linq as you mention using C# 2.0. The following uses a custom comparer to compare only the "EmpNo" codes in your file names. The solution expects your file names to be well-formed i.e. for them to contain an "EmpNo" in the format of your example file names.

```
    [Test]
    public void Sort()
    {
        string[] files = Directory
            .GetFiles(fbdialog.SelectedPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        Array.Sort(files, new EmpNoFileComparer());
    }

    private class EmpNoFileComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            string empNoX = Path.GetFileName(x).Split('-')[1];
            string empNoY = Path.GetFileName(y).Split('-')[1];

            return empNoX.CompareTo(empNoY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's better to use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` and don't use `SelectedPath.ToString()`

Comment: @abatishchev I'm using SelectedPath.ToString().

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure I follow you?

Comment: @Sam What problem are you having?

Comment: @chibacity I'm using C# 2005 Express Edition

Comment: @Sam I have provided an alternative answer which does not use Linq, as this is only available from C# 3.0 and you appear to be using C# 2.0. I would recommend upgrading if at all possible. C#2.0 is now quite *old*.

Comment: @Sam: Don't use `SelectedPath.ToString()`. Use just `SelectedPath`. It's already a string.

Answer (score 1):

Sort by filename:

```
var result = filePath.OrderBy(p => Path.GetFileName(p));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using some LINQ.
Note also that if you only need the file names, not the files themselves, then `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` can be used rather than `Directory.GetFiles()`.

```
var filePaths = new DirectoryInfo(fbdialog.SelectedPath.ToString())
    .GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .OrderBy(f => f.Name)
    .Select(f => f.FullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq; // requires .NET 3.5+

IEnumerable<string> r =
    new DirectoryInfo(fbdialog.SelectedPath) // no need for ToString()
        .GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Select(f => f.Name) // DAR-ALA061452-09050909.xls
        .Select(f => f.Substring(4, 9)) // ALA061452
        .OrderBy(f => f);
```

or shorter:

```
new DirectoryInfo(fbdialog.SelectedPath)
    .GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .OrderBy(f => f.Name.Substring(4, 9));
```

Comment: this could eventually work but not always, I think he should use System.Path.GetFileName() to isolate file name and sort by filename only ignoring the directory name...

Comment: @DavidePiras: First option for case if OP wants to order by date part.

Comment: The reason for downvote? If you don't understand something - ask.

Comment: I want to order by EmpNo(AAP070127).

Comment: @sam: You have several options: substring by known length (if the format is fixed) or using RegEx

Comment: @chibacity I'm using C# 2005 Express Edition

Comment: @Sam: Why don't use C# 2010 Express Edition? It's free as well and much more modern